# Why does array contain only last value n times?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, scope

This function returns the same value in the array list.

For example if `i=10`, then my array should contain 10 different values, but it stores only the last value 10 times.

What is the problem in my code?

```
$scope.webTempIds=[];
$scope.wId={};
$scope.getIds=function(){
  for(var i=0;i<$rootScope.retData.length;i++){
    $scope.wId.ID=$rootScope.retData[i].WEBUI_TEMP_ID;
    $scope.webTempIds.push($scope.wId);
  }
  return $scope.webTempIds;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you use `$scope` for `wId.ID` outside of loop. Therefore your list items point to the same object.

Once you change `$scope.wId.ID` , the list `$scope.webTempIds` will be updated too.

To fix it make id local:

```
for(var i=0;i<$rootScope.retData.length;i++){
     var wId = {
            ID: $rootScope.retData[i].WEBUI_TEMP_ID;
           }
     $scope.webTempIds.push(wId);
}
```

---

As a side note: use Scope to bind application controller and the view. (inside the `for` loop you don't need scope)

Answer (score 3):

```
$scope.wId={};
```

is changed every time. The array contains the reference to this object and hence when you change the value it changes the value in the array.

```js
let obj = {};

let result = [];
for(let i = 0; i<10; i++){
    obj.a = i;
    result.push(obj);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have correctly pointed out, you end up with the last item in the array because the value that you push to the array is on the `$scope` and gets replaced with the new value each time.

To offer an alternative approach, you could use the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to return a new array prepopulated with just the `id` property values of each data item:

```
$scope.getIds=function(){
  $scope.webTempIds = $rootScope.retData.map(
    function(obj){ 
      return obj.id; 
    }
  );
}
```

This eliminates the need for any loops with temporary variables and any `push`ing to manually build up a new array from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.getIds=function(){
        $scope.webTempIds=[];
        for(var i=0;i<$rootScope.retData.length;i++){
            $scope.wId={};
            $scope.wId.ID  =$rootScope.retData[i].WEBUI_TEMP_ID;
            $scope.webTempIds.push($scope.wId);
        }
return $scope.webTempIds;
    }
```